# Performance: use Webview to display images instead of ImageView

Tags: android, webview

In my Android `Activity`, I want to display about 10 images from web. Normally, I have to create 10 `ImageView` to display each image, but `ImageView` may cause `Out of memory exception`. So I decide to use 10 `WebView` to display image. It worked great.

But I don't know how performance of `WebView`, can anybody advise me how performance of 10 `WebViews` and Can I use this method to display images?

Comment: `But I don't know how performance of WebView`. Well YOU tried. So you can tell US. `can anybody advise me how performance of 10 WebViews`. The same!. `Can I use this method to display images?` ? I just heard you telling that it worrked great.

Comment: ImageView does not cause `OOM`, it the bitmap that you put inside that can cause it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView occupies more space in memory then image view . you won't get proper scaling in webView just by simply displaying images. Webview can be faster in popping image to Ui but its not the efficient way .

You can try Volly which has in build tool for image downloading,caching and scaling and i can insure you its quite fast also.

All you need to do is add the Volley library to your project and replace ImageView in your XML layout with com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.

Add the following variables to your Activity class:

```
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
Create the objects in the onCreate() method of your Activity:

mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10);

    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            mCache.put(url, bitmap);
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return mCache.get(url);
    }
});
```

Then download the image the getView() method of your Adapter class:

```
NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageUrl("http://someurl.com/someimage.png",mImageLoader);
```

In production code, you would use a global instance of both the RequestQueue and ImageLoader classes, and your onCreate() method wouldn't be cluttered as it is in this toy example.

I wouldn't use a webview to display images, though of course it can be done. If you really want to see which way is "faster", you can try out ImageView, NetworkImageView and WebView to load a large image and get a rough time estimate with the System.nanoTime() method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you display 10 images at the same time ?

If yes, the size of the image view must be relatively small, so you can use small version of your images and avoid out of memory errors (or download the real size but create in memory a small version).

If not, you should use a ListView or GridView or ViewPager or something that recycle the views. You only get a couple of them in memory at the same time and avoid out of memory errors.

Furthermore, there are excellent libraries to display download and display images, for instance Universal Image Loader will do everything in the background, resize the image to the required size, you can activate the memory cache / disk cache, etc.